# Where is the console app .net core program.cs file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I am looking for that file because I want to modify it, I found the file for the other console app .net framework, but can’t find this one. Can anyone help, I am creating hundreds of apps and am sick of manually deleting the namespace the hello world line and addin using libraries. Thank you and sorry if there is a similar question, I searched before I posted this and found nothing that can help me!

Comment: Its easy to create your own templates https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/how-to-locate-and-organize-project-and-item-templates

Comment: I tried that, but when I open my new created template, extracted from edited ConsoleApp(.NET Core), it doesn't contain the Program.cs file?

Comment: Good question. I searched my whole machine and only found one left over from a VS2015 install (definitely not relevant since it still has project.json). I hope you find the answer, I've been meaning to update mine to create asyc Main by default...